# How to setup a color per category accross all layers of a sunburst plotly graph in python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

I have a dataframe df like below:

```
step1    step2   step3   step4     occurances

Homepage Product Buy     Homepage 180
Homepage Product End     End      2000
Homepage End     End     End      150
Homepage Product Product Buy      100
```

I would like to create a sunburst to visualise the path of each customer.
So far, this is my code :

```
fig =px.sunburst(
    df,
    path = ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4'],
    values = 'occurrances',
    color ='step2'
)
fig.show()
```

However, I would like to define the colors per categories across each layer and not only layer 'step2' and keep the same color for each category in step 1, 2,3 and 4.
So I would like to go from this [old graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGSj.png) to this [new graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6iEO.png)
Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- basically you are defining that **color** is defined by **label**
- hence update `marker_color` with an appropriate **list comprehension**
- https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express have used **D3** as I found it works better

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""step1    step2   step3   step4     occurances
Homepage Product Buy     Homepage 180
Homepage Product End     End      2000
Homepage End     End     End      150
Homepage Product Product Buy      100"""), sep="\s+")

fig =px.sunburst(
    df,
    path = ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4'],
    values = 'occurances',
    color ='step2'
)
fig.update_traces(
    marker_colors=[
        px.colors.qualitative.D3[c] for c in pd.factorize(fig.data[0].labels)[0]
    ],
    leaf_opacity=1,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I tested it and it works